# Reading list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

How can we read the below list data and convert to pandas dataframe in python

```
[
  {"col1": "", "col2": "xx", "col3": "00001-1", "col4": "", "col5": "", "col6": "xx"},
  {"col1": "1", "col2": " aaa ", "col3": "00001-3", "col4": "0", "col5": "", "col6": "xx - abc"},
  {"col1": "1", "col2": "xx zzz", "col3": "00001-4", "col4": "0", "col5": "", "col6": "xx yyy"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_to_df(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)
    return df
```